# C++: vector containers and <algorithm> std::find

Tags: c++, vector, stl, iterator

I created a struct that contains information about variables, namely their name and number

```
struct var{
  string name;
  int value;
};
```

Now, I want to use iterators to update it, using the following function:

```
void updateVariable(vector<Variable>& vars,Variable& newVar){
    vector<Variable>::iterator it = find(vars.begin(), vars.end(), newVar);

    if(it == vars.end()){
        vars.push_back(newVar);
    }
    else{
        *it = newVar;
    }
}
```

Just to be sure, the error I'm getting is at the line with the call to find(). Any ideas why I'm getting the error? Here is the error:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algo.h:162:4: error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘__first.__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::operator* [with _Iterator = Variable*, _Container = std::vector<Variable>, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>::reference = Variable&]() == __val’
```

**Update:**

Thank you guys for all the quick help, and the clear answers!

Comment: You could use std::pair for just two values or tuple (I think) from C++11 for multiple values. Those have comparisons and equality operations already defined for you.

Comment: You should use a sorted vector and `std::binary_search`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You haven't defined `operator ==` for your `var` struct. The `find()` algorithm by default will use `operator ==` to compare the value you provide with the values in the specified range, and return the iterator to the first element which compares equal.

To fix this, just overload `operator ==` for your class. One way to do that is this:

```
struct var
{
    string name;
    int value;
};

bool operator == (var const& v1, var const& v2)
{
    return (v1.name == v2.name) && (v1.value == v2.value);
}
```

Make sure you define `operator ==` in the same namespace as your `var` structure, otherwise ADL (Argument Dependent Lookup) will fail and you will likely get a compiler error.

If you are working with C++11 and you do not want to bother defining an overloaded version of `operator ==`, you can even use `find_if()` and pass a lambda as the last argument:

```
find_if(vars.begin(), vars.end(), [&] (var const& v) { 
    return (v.name == newVar.name) && (v.value == newVar.value);
    });
```

As [GManNickG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87234/gmannickg) correctly points out, when you need to compare several members, using `std::tie` and the overloaded `operator ==` for `std::tuple` may save you some typing:

```
 auto const tieMembers = [] (const var&) { 
    return std::tie(v.name, v.value, ...);
    };
```

The above lambda can then be used this way when comparing values `v1` and `v2` of type `var`:

```
return (tieMembers(v1) == tieMembers(v2));
```

Comment: Perhaps useful to note is that if you want to compare several members, you can reuse `std::tuple`'s equality operator like so: `bool operator==(const var& v1, const var& v2) {const auto tieMembers = [](const var& v){ return std::tie(v.member1, v.member2, /* ... */); }; return tieMembers(v1) == tieMembers(v2); }`.

Comment: @GManNickG: Very nice. Edited

Answer (score 2):

You need to define an overload of `operator==` for `var`. This should work.

```
bool operator==(const var& a, const var& b){
  return (a.name == b.name) && (a.value == b.value);
}
```